# costmap_2d observation_sources: 'expected_update_rate'?

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In the sources for the navigation stack, there's a sample costmap_2d config file at navigation/costmap_2d/launch/example_params.yaml. In the part pertaining to the base_scan source, there's an undocumented parameter called 'expected_update_rate':

```
observation_sources: base_scan
base_scan: {data_type: LaserScan, expected_update_rate: 0.4,
  observation_persistence: 0.0, marking: true, clearing: true, max_obstacle_height: 0.4, min_obstacle_height: 0.08}
```

Is this what it sounds like (laser update rate in Hz)? 0.4 is kind of a weird value for a scanning laser so thought I'd check.

Thanks,

Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192109/costmap_2d-observation_sources:-%27expected_update_rate%27?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered my own question. It's really an "interval" rather than a "rate":

costmap_2d/src/observation_buffer.cpp:244:

```
bool ObservationBuffer::isCurrent() const
{
  if (expected_update_rate_ == ros::Duration(0.0))
    return true;

  bool current = (ros::Time::now() - last_updated_).toSec() <= expected_update_rate_.toSec();
  if (!current)
  {
    ROS_WARN(
        "The %s observation buffer has not been updated for %.2f seconds, and it should be updated every %.2f seconds.",
        topic_name_.c_str(), (ros::Time::now() - last_updated_).toSec(), expected_update_rate_.toSec());
  }
  return current;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2014-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2